# MySQL selecting data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join, multiple-tables

I have 2 mysql tables, **members** and **team_members**.

**members table:**

```
member_id
name
```

**team_members table:**

```
team_id
member_id
```

I want to select the data from the **members** table that do not belong to any team (do not exist in **team_members** table)

```
                    SELECT *
                    FROM members
                    INNER JOIN team_members
                    ON members.member_id = team_members.member_id
```

The problem is that the query is doing precisely the opposite i need. It is selecting the data from the members that already have a team.
I also tried with **'!='** but that gives me all fields duplicated, but does not duplicate the members that belong to a team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM members a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM team_members b
  WHERE b.member_id = a.member_id
  )
```

Notice this syntax follows very closely to how you phrased your question.  Sometimes SQL can be very easy; but like any language, you need to master the vocabulary.

Comment: yes i was missing that important syntax, just one question, what is the `SELECT 1` for ?

Comment: It's just a dummy value to satisfy SELECT syntax; just a placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

Use a left join, and select the records where there is no corresponding data from the `team_members` table:

```
select m.*
from members as m
left join team_members as t on m.member_id = t.member_id
where t.member_id is null
```